# pip install Chatterbot error installing the chatterbot erroevalue:source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, pip, chatterbot

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\usr\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7je3q7kg\pyyaml\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7je3q7kg\pyyaml\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2tpq4o8i'
cwd: C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7je3q7kg\pyyaml
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7je3q7kg\pyyaml\setup.py", line 91, in 
from wheel.bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ; also, please edit your question to format it so that it's more readable. However, to answer your question, it seems like you have a null byte (`\x0`) in the source code you're trying to install.

Comment: make sure the python version being used is supported by chatterbot. You can check on pypi

Comment: It worked chatterbox support python 3.6 mine was v3.8

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the previous version of ChatterBot.

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

This should work, unless there are some other problems. I had the same problem and it worked for me.

There would be another problem if you are using Python 3.8.x . In Python 3.8.x, a few functions of a few modules were removed. You will be able to import ChattberBot , but when you name the bot, there will be an error.

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 264, in <module>
time_func = time.clock
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Copy the location for the file given in the last line, where the error occurs.

```
C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py
```

Open file with IDLE or whatever editor you have. Please do Not open the file directly(this will run the file, and you will not be able to see the code) , instead Open with IDLE or Your Text editor Then , go to line 264 in that . It would be written

```
time_func = time.clock
```

Instead of this change it to

```
time_func = time.perf_counter()
```

I Hope this helped!